# SQL Server: two cursors iterate

Tags: sql-server, cursor, loops

In SQL Server, I have to use two cursor to iterate from two tables. But I have a problem with this because the result from the select with the two cursor is with duplicate rows. So my question is how to iterate from two or more cursors in SQL Server as you must know that the two cursors are depend on each other.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One cursor is bad enough, but you have _two_! Are you sure you can't solve your problem using set based constructs?

Comment: You should post your SQL - we can't tell what is going on just from your sparse description.

Comment: could you give me some example.

Comment: The main problem is that I do not know how to operate with two cursor in a sql statement.

Comment: The example should be coming from _you_, not us. What are you trying to achieve? Exactly? Posting examples of inputs and outputs would help.

Comment: I use two tables wich are temp. I haveto iterate over this two tables to make calcualtion and to output the info. But the iteration must be over the two tables at once. So I declare a main cursor and a sub cursor depending on the result ID from the main. I'm sorry but I  can't post a code here so please just give me an advise how to operate over two tables at once with two cursor?

Comment: I explained what is needed in order to help you.

Comment: Thanks I found what is the problem :)

Comment: Perhaps post the answer then?

Comment: I just have an error in the one of the insert statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make a distinct on the select and you don't have duplicate rows.

```
select distinct ... from tablename
```

---

But why in hell do you need two cursors? I **strongly** advise you to change that code!

Comment: Because I have to iterate in two table at once.

Comment: Roger that, try `distinct` then. If it doesn't work they are not duplicate and put some code.

Comment: OK but when you have a relation ship one to many for an example:
you have a table document and table for doc items. You cannot use distinct because you have to see all the result. The problem is that the item cursor doesn't work properly.